# Optimal Kakeya maximal bound for bushes

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\{T_{\alpha}\}$ be a collection of $1\times\cdots\times 1\times N$ tubes, where $N\gg 1$, with maximal $1/N$-separated directions, which all are centered at the origin (i.e. they form a bush). In a [note](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.02515v1.pdf) of A. Carbery, the author claims on pg. 4 that for such a collection, "it is easy to see" that the $\{T_{\alpha}\}$ satisfy the conjectured optimal Kakeya maximal bound
$$\|\sum_{\alpha}c_{\alpha}\chi_{T_{\alpha}}\|_{L^{\frac{n}{n-1}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\lesssim_{n}(\log N)^{\frac{n-1}{n}}N^{\frac{n-1}{n}}(\sum_{\alpha}|c_{\alpha}|^{\frac{n}{n-1}})^{\frac{n-1}{n}}$$
for all scalars $c_{\alpha}$.

I am having difficulty seeing that this is case. I can show this in dimension $2$ by using the fact that $\frac{n}{n-1}=2$ and multiplying out the integrand. For higher dimensions, I tried dyadically decomposing space and using Holder's inequality, but this didn't give me the right bound due to too crude an estimate on the measure of the domain of integration.

---

Partition the ball $B(0,N)$ into the ball $B(0,1)$ and annuli $A_{j}:=\{j\leq|x|<j+1\}$, for $1\leq j\leq N-1$. Now partition each $A_{j}$ into $\sim j^{n-1}$ caps $\{S_{\beta,j}\}$ of diameter $\sim 1$, and let $e_{\beta,j}$ denote the normalized center of $S_{\beta,j}$. On the ball $B(0,1)$, we use Holder's inequality together with the fact that there are $\sim N^{n-1}$ tubes $T_{\alpha}$ to get

$$\int_{B(0,1)}|\sum_{\alpha}c_{\alpha}\chi_{T_{\alpha}}|^{\frac{n}{n-1}}\leq (\sum_{\alpha}|c_{\alpha}|^{\frac{n}{n-1}})\int_{B(0,1)}(\sum_{\alpha}\chi_{T_{\alpha}})^{\frac{1}{n-1}}\lesssim_{n}N\sum_{\alpha}|c_{\alpha}|^{\frac{n}{n-1}}\tag{1}$$

Fix $1\leq j\leq N$. The tube $T_{\alpha}$ doesn't intersect $S_{\beta,j}$ if $|e_{\alpha}-e_{\beta,j}|>\frac{10}{j}$. Since $\#\{\alpha : |e_{\alpha}-e_{\beta,j}|\leq\frac{10}{j}\}=O((N/j)^{n-1})$, we see that $|\sum_{\alpha}\chi_{T_{\alpha}\cap A_{j}}|\lesssim_{n} (N/j)^{n-1}$. Applying Holder's inequality, we have the bound

$$\sum_{\beta}\int_{S_{\beta,j}}|\sum_{\alpha}c_{\alpha}\chi_{T_{\alpha}}|^{\frac{n}{n-1}}\lesssim_{n}\sum_{\beta}\sum_{\alpha\atop{|e_{\alpha}-e_{\beta,j}|\leq\frac{10}{j}}}|c_{\alpha}|^{\frac{n}{n-1}}(N/j) \tag{2}$$

Now for $j$ and $\alpha$ fixed, $\#\{\beta : |e_{\alpha}-e_{\beta,j}|\leq\frac{10}{j}\}\lesssim_{n}1$. Therefore (2) is

$$\lesssim_{n}\frac{N}{j}\sum_{\alpha}|c_{\alpha}|^{\frac{n}{n-1}}$$

Summing over $j$, we conclude that

$$\|\sum_{\alpha}c_{\alpha}\chi_{T_{\alpha}}\|_{L^{\frac{n}{n-1}}}^{\frac{n}{n-1}}\lesssim_{n}N(\sum_{\alpha}|c_{\alpha}|^{\frac{n}{n-1}})\sum_{j}\frac{1}{j}\lesssim N(\log N)\sum_{\alpha}|c_{\alpha}|^{\frac{n}{n-1}} \tag{3}$$

Comment: Try breaking the integrand on the left into two components. Component 1 should be a ball around the origin on which the tubes may overlap. Component 2 should be the set on which no two tubes overlap.

Comment: @MarkLewko: Thank you for your comment. I edited my question to include the argument up with which I came. Is it what you had in mind?

Comment: @MarkLewko: If the $|e_{\alpha}-e_{\alpha'}|\sim 1/N$, then $T_{\alpha}$ $T_{\alpha'}$ intersect on the ball $B(0,N/2)$ and are contained in the ball $B(0,N/2)$. I don't see how your argument works. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Ack, yes, you're right.